# Where is my Log4J level being set?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

The following is my Log4J code :

```
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;



public class HelloWorldLog4J {

 private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");


  //private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldLog4J.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("pre_loggerDOTinfo");
        System.out.println();
        //logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);   //used to be.. 

        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        logger.warn("Hello, this is an WARN  message");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message ALSO, #2");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message ALSO, #3");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message ALSO, #4");
        logger.debug("Hello, this is an FATAL  message");

        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("post_loggerDOTinfo");

    }


}
```

This works when I run it, and outputs the following :

> pre_loggerDOTinfo
>
> 12:21:20.761 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message 12:21:20.763 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL
>   message ALSO, #2
>
> 12:21:20.764 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message ALSO, #3
>
> 12:21:20.765 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message ALSO, #4
>   11
>
> post_loggerDOTinfo

This is fine , but I want it to output *all* of the logging messages, not just the FATAL ones.

So what I tried is to create a log4j.properties file in the same directory as the Java file. It is here :

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file
log4j.appender.console=DEBUG,org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.file=INFO,org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender



log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log4j.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=512KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
```

But when I re-run the HelloWorldLog4J class, I get the same exact thing (as if it's finding a properties file elsewhere ).

I think that I need to set the log4j properties file within my HelloWorldLog4J   class?  I did try this , using the line :

```
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

However, this doesn't work - and I get this error :

```
HelloWorldLog4J.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);   //used to be..
              ^
  symbol:   method setLevel(Level)
  location: variable logger of type Logger
1 error

C:\Users\Adel\JavaCoding>
```

any tips appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are importing any library with a custom log4.properties file, or your properties file is not visible on the classpath

See here for a discussion on how to setup
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit

You could try to set the `log4j.configuration` property when starting your class.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration="PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE"
```

And see if this is now picked up

Comment: Thanks so much !! I will try the `log4j.configuration` property, and also read up on log4